# refreshing captcha code using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, captcha

In my page I have an `img` that shows `captcha` code and one `img` that refreshes the `captcha` code, not whole page, when clicked. in `chrome` it works very well and refreshes the code every time it is clicked, but in `IE` nothing happens when the `img` is clicked and for refreshing the `captcha` code you have to reload the page.
how can I solve this problem in `IE`?

```
<img name="capImg" id="capImg" src="php/captcha.php">
<img src="images/recaptcha.png" onClick="resetCap();">
```

script:

```
function resetCap(){
    var ajaxRequest;
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('capImg').src = "php/captcha.php";
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "php/captcha.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

captcha.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$backImage = imagecreatefrompng('C:\xampp\htdocs\service\images\captchaBack.png');
$shadowColor = imagecolorallocate($backImage, 150, 150, 150);
$textColor = imagecolorallocate($backImage, 50, 50, 50);
$font_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\service\fonts\times_new_yorker.ttf';
$text = NULL;
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++) $text .= mt_rand(0,9);
$_SESSION['capCode'] = $text;
imagettftext($backImage, 28, 2, 13, 38, $shadowColor, $font_path, $text);
imagettftext($backImage, 28, 2, 15, 40, $textColor, $font_path, $text);

header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($backImage);
imagedestroy($backImage);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a unique parameter that will make browser retrieve the image again and not look into the cache. You don't need Ajax here:

```
function resetCap(){
    document.getElementById('capImg').src = 
                           "php/captcha.php?" + new Date().getTime();  
}
```

This is all you need.

Comment: I tested it, the first click after each page reload works and changes the code, but next clicks don't do anything in IE

Comment: @Masoud I updated the answer. Did you clean the cache on IE using Ctrl-F5?

Comment: thank you very much. this is the answer and works in IE very well, but I didn't know that this can be done without using Ajax.